# Default background value of element within html

Tags: javascript

How come the first alert is blank?
And only contains a value after I've explicitly set my custom value?
Surely there is a default value that I should be seeing. I'd like to retrieve that default value so I can use it in a `Reset to defaults` button later.

Basic `<div>` on screen, no custom styling applied to element ..

```
<div id="test">Hello</div>
```

Some javascript to show the background color of `#test` ..

```
alert(document.getElementById('test').style.background);
document.getElementById('test').style.background = '#999000';
alert(document.getElementById('test').style.background);
```

jsFiddle ..

http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/esnpL0cd/

Comment: because the default is transparent!

Comment: might i suggest adding/removing a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `<div>` has a default transparent background and it's default `.style.background` is `""`. This is why your `alert` prints out nothing.

To reset the background to transparent, you can assign `""` to it's `.style.background`.

```
document.getElementById('test').style.background = '';
```

Any value, you get from `.style.background` can be stored and used to assign to `.style.background` again.